# LiveSpeech iterator returns no errors and no results on macOS

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

I've installed the [Python interface](https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python) to pocketsphinx in a virtual environment using `venv` on macOS:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip3 install --upgrade pocketsphinx
```

but when I run the basic example:

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
for phrase in LiveSpeech():
    print(phrase)
```

it returns no results. The default microphone is functional in other programs. I've dumped the verbose debug info [here](https://pastebin.com/6BpG4mRR).

(Note: I have pocketsphinx installed globally as well, and when I run `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes` it returns streaming recognition results correctly.

How I can pin down what is going wrong with the Python interface?

Comment: A guess--do you have to allow the Python executable access to the microphone in the Security and Privacy part of System Preferences?